# Button text changes from Goobye to Hello after 2 clicks?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

For some reason, whenever I use this in my React TS project, I need to press the button twice to change the text from "Goodbye" to "Hello" but not the other way around?

```
import { useState } from 'react' 

const ChangeTextButton = () => {

    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Click me!")
    var changedBefore = false;

    function changeText() {
        
        if (changedBefore) {
            setButtonText("Hello")
        } else {
            setButtonText("Goodbye")
        }
        
        changedBefore = !changedBefore
        return buttonText;
    }

    return(
        <button onClick={() => changeText()}>{buttonText}</button>
    );
}

export default ChangeTextButton;
```

Yeah, I know this is bad code, I'm relatively new to TypeScript and JS as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because your `changedBefore` variable will be set to `false` after each rerender.

So it starts from `false`, at the first click it change the text button to "Goodbye" and rerender. The rerender will put set the value back to `false` again. The next click will change the text to "Goodbye" again, but since it's the same state as the actual one, it won't trigger a rerender so your `changedBefore` will be `true` for next click, that will finally change text to "Hello"

If you want to avoid this behavior you will have to use `useState` or `useRef` for your `changedBefore` variable, like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react' 

const ChangeTextButton = () => {

    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Click me!")
    const [changedBefore, setChangedBefore] = useState(false);

    function changeText() {
        
        if (changedBefore) {
            setButtonText("Hello")
        } else {
            setButtonText("Goodbye")
        }
        
        setChangedBefore(cb => !cb)
    }

    return(
        <button onClick={() => changeText()}>{buttonText}</button>
    );
}

export default ChangeTextButton;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wuulup?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought it might have something to do with that